# Navigation bar flies to the bottom

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a navigation bar BELOW two icons/logos, but it flies to the bottom of the page, OR overlays the 2 logos. A live version is available at http://ddlgaming.com/giga/

This is my code so far:
(Please ignore some of the color:white, it's to help me see better.)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/mainframe.css" type="text/css" rel=stylesheet>
<script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>

<body>

<!--Giga logo, top left--!>
<div id="gigalogomainbox">
    <div id="gigalogobox">
        <img id="gigalogo" src="images/gigalogo.png">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
    </div>
</div>

<!--Steam logo, top right--!>
<div id="steamlogomainbox">
    <div id="steamlogobox">
        <img id="steamlogo" src="images/steamlogo.png">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
    </div>
</div>


<!--navigation barrrrrr--!>
<div id="navbarbox">
    <ul id="navbar">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Servers</li>
        <li>Community</li>
        <li>Store</li>
        <li>Download</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.clearfix   {
            clear: both;
            }

body
            {
            background-color: rgb(21,14,43);
            background-image: url("../images/backgroundimage.jpg");
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            min-height: 100%;
            background-position: center center;
            overflow: hidden;
            }

#gigalogomainbox
            {
            float: left;
            width: 30%;
            height: 50vw;
            overflow: hidden;
            transform: skewX(20deg);
            }

#gigalogobox
            {
            margin: 0 3vw 0 5vw;
            padding: 0 0 0 2vw;
            background-color: white;
            width: 80%;
            height: 20%;
            }

#gigalogo
            {
            width: 90%;
            float: left;
            margin: 2.5vw 2vw 0 0;
            }

#steamlogomainbox
            {
            width: 10%;
            height: 50vw;
            float: right;
            overflow: hidden;
            }

#steamlogobox
            {
            margin: 0 -2vw 0 3vw;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 20%;
            float: right;
            background-color: white; /*000c21*/
            transform: skewX(-20deg);

            }
#steamlogo
            {
            width: 65%;
            float: right;
            margin: 3vw 2vw 0 0;
            transform: skewX(20deg);
            }

#placeholderbartop
            {
            float: left;
            width: 60%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 10vw;
            }


#navbarbox          
            {
            width: 100%;
            }
#navbar, #navbar ul
            {
            width: 100%;
            height: 5vw;
            margin: 0;
            color: white;
            background-color: white;
            display: inline-block;
            }

#navbar li
            {
            color: white;
            list-style: none;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 1vw;
            color: red;
            font-size: 30px;
            }
```

Comment: first thing you need to know is the order in which you are placing your tags. like here your nav bar is at the bottom, are you sure you put this at bottom? and plz if you can make a graphic mock-up of what you want it would be really helpful for others to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set a height of 50vw on your logos. So it's taking half the screen height (50vw = 50% of the view width), what you want is set the height as the same as your image height (50px? px = pixels). Then, it's pushing the rest to the bottom.

Comment: Thank you! I must have been blind to ignore that

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for?

```css
body
{
  background-color: rgb(21,14,43);
  background-image: url("../images/backgroundimage.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#navbarbox   
{
  width: 100%;
}
#navbar, #navbar ul
{
  width: 90%;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}
#gi {
  margin-top: -10px;
  width:80px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}   
#steam{
  margin-top: -10px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 70px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#navbar li
{
  color: white;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top:15px;
  padding-right: 1%;
  color: red;
  font-size: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbarbox">
  <ul id="navbar">
    <li><img id="gi"     src="http://ddlgaming.com/giga/images/gigalogo.png"></li>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Servers</li>
    <li>Community</li>
    <li>Store</li>
    <li>Download</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li><img id="steam" src="http://ddlgaming.com/giga/images/steamlogo.png"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```